# delete duplicates words from column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a `dataframe` like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Stay home, T5006, T5006, Stay home', 'Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Go for walk'],
                    'Name': ['Stay home, Go for walk,  Stay home', 'Go outside, Go outside, Go outside']
                    })


    ID                                      Name
0   Stay home, T5006, T5006, Stay home      Stay home, Go for walk, Stay home
1   Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Go for walk  Go outside, Go outside, Go outside
```

I want to delete the dulicates from `ID` column. Expected outcome:

```
    ID                  Name
0   Stay home,T5006     Stay home,  Go for walk, Stay home
1   Go for walk,T5007   Go outside, Go outside,  Go outside
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `dict.fromkey` trick for remove duplicates of splitted values, then join by `,`  in lambda function:

```
df3['ID'] = df3['ID'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(dict.fromkeys(x.split(', '))))
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
df3['ID'] = [', '.join(dict.fromkeys(x.split(', '))) for x in df3['ID']]

print (df3)
                   ID                                Name
0    Stay home, T5006  Stay home, Go for walk,  Stay home
1  Go for walk, T5007  Go outside, Go outside, Go outside
```

Of if possible order is not important use `set`s:

```
df3['ID'] = df3['ID'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split(', '))))
df3['ID'] = [', '.join(set(x.split(', '))) for x in df3['ID']]
print (df3)
                   ID                                Name
0    Stay home, T5006  Stay home, Go for walk,  Stay home
1  T5007, Go for walk  Go outside, Go outside, Go outside
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what `dict.fromkeys` does

Comment: @KarthikS - Sure, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016257/2901002)

Comment: Thanks, so basically it converts a list or set into unique key value pairs, 
if value is not given `None` is taken as default. didn't know `''.join` joins dictionary keys. Thanks!